# Why isn't the template rendering the correct values?

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, template-engine

I have a template which iterates through a map and displays the info as such:

```
       #{list items:report.getCategoryMap()?.keySet(), as:'cat'}
           %{models.reporting.TransactionReportItem item = report.getCategoryMap()?.get(cat);}%
            
              ${cat}
              ${item?.nbCredit}
              ${item?.getCreditPerc(report.nbCredit)}
              ${item?.nbDebit}
              ${item?.getDebitPerc(report.nbDebit)}
              ${item?.getTotalTransactions()}
            
       #{/list}
```

for some reason the template always render the result of getCreditPerc and getDebitPerc as 0.0

```
    public Double getCreditPerc(long totalCredit){
        double perc = (double) (nbCredit / totalCredit);
        Logger.info("nbCredit: %s, total cr: %s", nbCredit, totalCredit);
        return new Double(perc);
    }
```

When calling the template I can see the output in the log:

**2011-11-21 13:54:22  INFO ~ [TransactionReportItem:85] getDebitPerc() - nbDebit: 39, total cr: 4984**

I tried using primitive type instead of double object with no success.
When debugging the code I can see that all the values are correctly set.

Could it be something to do with the groovy template rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the log from a different function doesn't help this question along ;-)

However, the problem is that you have two `ints` in Java, and you are dividing them so you get integer division...

Casting this integer then to a `double` is too late...

Try:

```
double perc = (double)nbCredit / totalCredit ;
```

Comment: didn't see your post and I posted the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

A stupid idea from me. Isn't it simply a problem in the code?

```
int nbCredit=39;
int total=4984;
double perc = (double) (nbCredit / totalCredit); // gives 0
```

nbCredit/total is an division of integers with result < 1 so it might be rounded to 0

did you try with :

```
double perc =  (double)nbCredit / totalCredit;
```